# Laravel routes for user profiles? without /user

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel Routing:

I wanna make profile users with a URL nice: `example.com/steve`

Actually I have: `example.com/user/steve`

When I make the routing update this works:

```
Route::get('{username}', ['as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@show']);
```

But when I try enter to another routes (/guide):

```
Route::get('guide', ['as' => 'guide', 'uses' => 'GuestController@showGuide']);
```

This "collapse" with the user profiles route. How can I make that works without 404 errors?

I wanna try with a different method that "the i method" (put the letter i before all the URLs: Route::get('i/guide'))

Answer (score 2):

Laravel matches listed routes from top to bottom. So `\{username}` will match `\{anyword}`

One of the ways to workaround this is;

In your routes.php `Route::get('guide', ['as' => 'guide', 'uses' => 'GuestController@showGuide']);` should come first.

Let `Route::get('{username}', ['as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@show']);` be placed after every other routes

Answer (score 1):

You should first create the route for guide

```
Route::get('guide', ['as' => 'guide', 'uses' => 'GuestController@showGuide']);
```

and then for user

```
Route::get('{username}', ['as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@show']);
```

the sequence does matter in routes.php file. If the {username} route is above guide route then it will treat guide as {username} and hence redirect you accordingly but then you dont have a user with a username guide

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'i'], function()
{
    Route::get('guide', function()
    {
        // Matches The "/i/guide" URL
    });
});
```

Group the routes and add prefix to them.